# Place Canvas inside table cell

Tags: css, canvas, html-table, position

I am trying to place a canvas inside the left table cell in the code below, but it always plots below the table.  (I am an ancient C programmer, new to HTML and using Kompozer to create the table).  I apologize for the stupidity of this question - I have attempted numerous Google searches and scanned through multiple Canvas PDFs without success.

```
...
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Canvas Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 982px; height: 604px;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 748px;"><br>
    <canvas id="samplecanvas" width="512" height="300"> This text is
    displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas. </canvas>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 214px;"><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me.... I plugged your code in (with an doctype, html & head tags) and I saw the canvas in the table in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Strange - I am using firefox and the canvas plots BELOW the two table elements.

Comment: Just checked Firefox on my work Mac - it renders correctly there too. Your markup looks fine to me, on top of it. No missing end tags or anything (though it would be nicer if you had a / on the br tag (<br />). Is the markup in the dots compliant too?

Comment: I will experiment a bit on different machines.  I am presently on Firefox "17" on Scientific (RedHat) Linux 6.4.  (The preceding ... are "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>" as you guessed previously.)  The table HTML was generated by Kompozer (including the <br>) - would have expected that was compliant but I will check more carefully.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Looks good to me, and it renders correctly to boot! Maybe you have a cache issue?